# What does »du« mean in: »Du, das ist aber ein super Auto«?

Tags: word-usage

What does *du* mean in:

> **Du,** das ist aber ein super Auto.

Another example would be:

> **Du,** ich kenne jetzt schon 3 Leute hier.

I have transcribed these sentences myself, so take them with a pinch of salt.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Latin this would be vocative. It is used to address the receiver of the message and to get his/her attention. In German it is syntactically not a part of the following sentence. Its more like a one-word-sentence (an exclamation) before the rest of the message.

You can think of it as a shortened form of:

> Hey **you,** (please) listen!

Comment: I can hear that now in the intonation.

Answer (score 6):

The German term for this form of address is [*»Anredenominativ«*](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Anredenominativ).

Other sample:

> Mama, ich hab Hunger!

Also a leading *»o«* can be added:

> O Kind, du hast wieder alles verstellt!
>
> [O Tannenbaum ...](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Anredenominativ)

where *[»O Tannenbaum«](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/O_Tannenbaum)* is the beginning of a Christmas carol.

Comment: Or simply like "Joseph, kannst du mir mal den Wein rüberreichen?" However, starting with "Du" adds intimacy.